# How can i query the result of the hook response?

Tags: react-hooks-testing-library

Is it possible to query the DOM that is returned by when the hook is rendered?

```
const {current} = renderHook(...)
current.querySelector('xxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming your test is running in an environment with a DOM (e.g. jsdom/jest) and you've got something there to query.

*Note: `current` is not a root level export of `renderHook`. You must use `result.current` instead:*

```js
const {result} = renderHook(...)
result.current.querySelector('xxx')
```

Comment: TypeError: result.current.querySelector is not a function